# Why do non-linear functions have to be in V or U shape, why can't it just be one line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, linear-transformations

The title says it all really, I just don't get why you can't just use one line.

Comment: It seems kind of tautological, that non-linear functions shouldn't literally be a line, doesn't it? However, in some contexts, a function $f$ must satisfy $f(0) = 0$ to be called *linear*, in which case a function like $f(x) = x + 2$ would indeed not be called linear (although its graph is a line).

Comment: There are many shapes other than V or U shapes that non-linear functions can be.  For elementary examples, consider $e^x, \sin(x), \tan(x),\lfloor x\rfloor,\dots$.  For more exotic examples, consider the [devil's staircase](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html) (Cantor's function) or the [raindrop function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) (Thomae's function).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a "straight line", then it's because a function with such a graph is always linear (so, not non-linear).

Linear functions are precisely those whose graphs are (nonvertical) lines.

I'm assuming we're talking about real-valued functions of a single real variable (functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$).

Comment: https://aoa.sooschools.com/media/g_pal_2015/5/img_nonlinear5.gif So why isn't that a straight line

Comment: Because, well, it isn't a line nor is it straight. So calling it a straight line would be a bit... off.

Comment: Though, in some contexts, the set of linear functions can be considered as a specific subset of the set of nonlinear functions.

Comment: @Karlo: I can't imagine how, unless you say "nonlinear" when you really mean "not necessarily linear"

Comment: @MPW Exactly, that's how my control engineering professor used the term "nonlinear".